# Why does WinSCP connect to /root and nothing else, through OpenSSH?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, root, winscp

We set up an Amazon EC2 instance and managed to WinSCP into it by setting up WinSSHD on the server.

As WinSSHD is commercial, we were looking for a free alternative and opted to try OpenSSH, which I have always heard good things about.

After installing Cygwin with OpenSSH and starting up OpenSSH from the Cygwin console, I attempted to WinSCP into the server from my computer, and got access to /root that contains files like Cygwin.bat and such.

I was wondering if I had done something wrong during the setup, or if I have to change the sshd_config file for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't setup a standard user. As such, you're connecting with root. Consider adding a regular user and specifying that users login credentials when connecting.